# Symfony2 routing error (parameter <x> for route <r> must match <pattern>)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm kind of new in Symfony2 Framework. This error take forever me to solved. I build my own project based from Jobeet tutorial. Now I've success till generate CRUD but when opening index page I got route error like this :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "id" for route "sifo_mst_periode_show" must match "[^/]++"
>   ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in
>   SifoSchoolBundle:MstPeriode:index.html.twig at line 21.

This is my index.html.twig line 21 :

```
<td><a href="{{ path('sifo_mst_periode_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
```

This is the route :

```
sifo_mst_periode:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "SifoSchoolBundle:MstPeriode:index" }

sifo_mst_periode_show:
    pattern:  /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "SifoSchoolBundle:MstPeriode:show" }
```

And this is the routing :

```
SifoSchoolBundle_sifo_mst_periode:
    resource: "@SifoSchoolBundle/Resources/config/routing/mstperiode.yml"
    prefix:   /periode
```

Comment: make sure `entity.id` have some value

Comment: How do you initialize `entity`? If its in a loop make sure you check if `entity.id` is empty or null!

Comment: @PCoder : Atually im using generate:crud command based Jobeet tutorial day 3 http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/09/symfony2-jobeet-day-3-the-data-model/
Its auto generated.

Comment: How about placing an if condition to check whether its empty or null?

Comment: @PCoder : Its NULL. Seems the form which auto generated not put PK in the form. Normally in PHP, I do input manually the Primary Key. 
Im sorry if this is become out of topic. But am I must change all PK to auto? so it will be generated without interaction from user instead make new field as Code for user interface.

Comment: Generally, its up to you to decide whether you set PK to auto or not. If you handle generating the PK in your code, then you can set it in the create statement else you let is auto.

Comment: @PCoder : Im sorry if this question bother you, but Im lack of experience. Is it better to make all PK auto as normal Symfony2 id behaviour? Thank you before. And btw Case Solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Case has been solved. The problem is Primary Key (entity.id) had NULL Value which not show in Add Form. I make all Primary Key to auto and not handle by User Form.

Thank You.